DXA 2.3 .NET Redis Timeout When Used With DXA Cache Regions
When using RedisCacheHandler for the following DXA cache regions: PageModel, EntityModel, Navigation_Static, Navigation_Dynamic, BinaryPublishDate, LinkResolving, PublicationMapping, BrokerQuery. RedisCacheHandler returns timeour error:
ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.RedisCache.RedisCacheHandler`1.Get]
    Redis Timeout '***:6379' due to System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 56, queue: 31, qu: 0, qs: 31, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 131072, ar: 0, clientName: CC, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=106,Free=32661,Min=8,Max=32767), Local-CPU: unavailable (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md)
       at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
       at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
       at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisExtensions.HashMemberGet(IDatabase cache, String key, String[] members)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.RedisCache.GetAndRefresh(String key, Boolean getData)
       at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.RedisCache.RedisCacheHandler`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<TryGet>b__0()
       at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.RedisCache.RedisCacheHandler`1.RetryBlock[TResult](Func`1 block, TResult& returnedValue).

In addition to the desired help with the timeout issue, I have the following questions:

It is mentioned in web.config: We should use the multi-level cache for these ideally with a level 1 cache enabled How to implement multi-level cache? could not find any sample in the documentation
Is RedisCacheHandler preferable for those DXA Regions?
How to further configure RedisCacheHandler to use the available options listed here?


Can't comment on how to use multi-level cache (question #1), and I would guess whether switching over to the RedisCacheHandler is highly implementation specific (question #2).  Some suggestions on using the RedisCacheHandler with DXA, and using RedisCache configuration options (question #3) below.
Distributed caching through Redis is provided through the deprecated CIL library that DXA uses, and unfortunately does not expose configuration options and would require CIL code changes to implement. As the CIL library is deprecated, new functionality will not be developed for it by RWS. However possible custom implementation suggestions are outlined in KB article HERE.
